# No response when call button click in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, code-behind

Good day,

I have a aspx contain a button with ID button1, the following is my aspx code :

```
<div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" CommandName="VIEW" runat="server">View</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="button1_Click" />
</div>
/*
some code here
*/
<script>
function test()
            {
                document.getElementById("<%=button1.ClientID %>").click();
alert("hello");
    return true;
            }
</script>
```

The following is my aspx code behind:

```
//some code here
lnkView.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return test()");
//some code here

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('Record Added Successfully')</script>", false);     
    }
```

As you can see, my linkView link button have a javascript function test() when click on it.
I can alert the "Record Added Successfully" by click on the Button1.
However, when I click on linkView link button, the "Record Added Successfully" didnt alert, it only alert "Hello".

I think I am missunderstand in some programming concept. 
Kindly advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger the event in code behind.

Try this in your .aspx page:

//Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(parameter)
{
  __doPostBack('button1_Click', parameter)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by returning *false* instead of *true* as the result of the function *test()*. This way you will cancel default behavior of the link with ID lnkView ie sending form